# CSV writer - writing to csv as the script runs but does not save

Tags: python, csv

My code appears to be working and saving down data to the csv but after the script ends, there is no data. As the script is running, my csv file stores the data and if I interrupt it, I can see some data.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def main():

    page = 1
    page_has_data = True 
    while page_has_data:

        r = requests.get("http://scrapethissite.com/pages/forms/", params=dict(per_page=100, page_num=page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="lxml")

        print("----- Scraping page number", page)
        page += 1

        teams = soup.findAll("tr", "team")
        if len(teams) == 0:
            page_has_data = False

        with open("hockey_stats.csv", "w", newline="") as results:
            writer = csv.writer(results)

            for team in teams:
                team_name = team.find("td", "name").get_text(strip=True)
                team_year = team.find("td", "year").get_text(strip=True)
                team_win = team.find("td", "wins").get_text(strip=True)
                team_loss = team.find("td", "losses").get_text(strip=True)
                team_pct_win = team.find("td", "pct text-success")
                team_goalsfor = team.find("td", "gf").get_text(strip=True)
                team_goalsagainst = team.find("td", "ga").get_text(strip=True)
                team_plus_minus = team.find("td", "diff text-success")
                writer.writerow([team_name, team_year,team_win, team_loss, team_pct_win, team_goalsfor, team_goalsagainst, team_plus_minus])

            results.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `with open("hockey_stats.csv", "a")`

The last entry is wiping off the previous data as it is in "w" mode and the last entry to the file is empty. Appending works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two issues with your snippet.  You are opening the file in write mode.  Instead open it it append mode("a").  When you are iterating over, with new requests, you end up overwriting the data you last wrote to the file (if the file is opened in write mode - "w").  The last request will not have any data, and you overwrite your file with empty data.

Secondly, you don't need 'results.close()'.  The with statement will take care of closing the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to fix this. First, open file with 'a' mode. Or, open your file out of the while loop. In your code, whenever loop starts again, it starts with an empty file